# Xcode6: Navigation Bar Overlaps with top of iphone, like the time , etc

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, swift

how can i space this better? i've read the similar questions of SO, but none seem to answer it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qadQa.jpg

Comment: do you mean it overlaps with the status bar?

Comment: yes, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: trying to, tho the option doesnt seem to be available for nav bars...

Answer (score 0):

I would select the navigation bar in storyboard, then add a constraint to the top of the screen (say, 16 pixels).